# Is it a bad practice to cite URLs as references in comments?

Tags: comments

Sometimes I think it's useful to cite a webpage (*e.g.* Stack Overflow questions) to justify and explain a piece of code. Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: If recreating the reference would make it massive:  [Hell yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

Answer (score 5):

You may put URLs inside your comments, but consider the problems it might raise:

- No-one actually copies the link, and goes to read what the content of the URL actually say.
- The link/site might not be there a year in the future, or even next week
- You might forget to update the comment when the code below it changes, which will confuse a future reader even further.

I believe that you should not put URLs inside your comments *unless* you also paste the **relevant quote** from it, and then the URL is only used as a re-enforcement for the comment, or as in-depth further reading.

Comment: Bullet 2 is why I try to only do this with StackOverflow, since we try to [actively fight link rot here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140772/link-rot-encourage-author-to-cache-snippets-of-relevant-text-to-prepare-for-thi)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you and your team are disciplined about comments, sure.

Use long-term reliable sites for your references:

a) wiki or other internal sites maintained by your team for the life of the project.

b) internal sites maintained by your organization that have a long-term maintenance agreement regarding preserving links.

c) external sites that have commitments to long-term maintenance of links. E.g., wikipedia, stack exchange, open source vendor sites, etc.

The alternatives to putting links into your comments are often worse.

1) Multiple maintenance: don't repeat yourself in an explanation of a coding instance, especially when it affects multiple pieces of source code.

2) Trying to summarize a board discussion when you've already implemented the code is frequently redundant.